# Ajax function how to pass to success data result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a function of ajax that is reusable. However, I am experiencing trouble as follow. The data return is dependent on the web api and i want to make it render accordingly to parameter input.

```js
// Ajax call
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'GET",
    data: { },
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data.LanguageList, function(index,value) {
         // Perform action
      });
    }
});

// Make into function (fail)
function loadAjax(param1) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'GET",
    data: { },
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(param1, function(index,value) {
         // Perform action
      });
    }
  })
}

loadAjax(data.LanguageList);
```

Comment: What is not working ? Your question needs more description..

Comment: @RayonDabre data is undefined

Comment: You have data inside this `data.LanguageList` when calling a function?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali yes there is data inside data.languagelist, but the data is only available when ajax success function is executed, not when the function LoadAjax is call.

Comment: Why don't you call `loadAjax` inside `success` function??